# Table Header text fills two lines

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a lot of columns. How do I do it so that the table header titles stay on a line. I want them to all stretch on a single line. This is the html. This might have been asked before, I just do not how the right words to search it.

```html
<div class="overflow-auto">
    <table class="table" style="word-wrap:break-word;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="line-height:1" class="border-b-2 dark:border-dark-5 whitespace-no-wrap">Transponder Type</th>
                <th style="line-height:1" class="border-b-2 dark:border-dark-5 whitespace-no-wrap">Frequency Check</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var s in data)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="line-height:1" class="border-b whitespace-no-wrap">@s.Trans</td>
                    <td style="line-height:1" class="border-b whitespace-no-wrap">@shipment.Freq</td>
```

Comment: Or you can change the width of the column in %.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in css:

```
.table thead tr th {white-space:nowrap}
```

or in `style` tag on each `<th>`:

```
<th style="line-height:1; white-space:nowrap" class="border-b-2 dark:border-dark-5 whitespace-no-wrap">Transporter Name</th>
```

Also, check if `whitespace-no-wrap` class is being called properly or not.